# Fibonacci sequence array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, beginner, fibonacci-sequence

This is my third day of learning Javascript through an online class. I learned about arrays and while/for loops today, and to practice all of that stuff the challenge I'm working on is to make a function that produces \$(n)\$ terms of the Fibonacci sequence in an array.

So I'm hoping for some feedback on this code! I think it works but I would like to know how I could make it more efficient or better in any way.

```
function fibonacciGenerator (n) {
    var output=[];
    if (n===1) {
      output=[0];
    } else if (n===2) {
      output=[0,1];
    } else if (n>2) {
      output=[0,1];
      for (var i=3;i<=n;i++) {
        output.push(output[i-3]+output[i-2]);
      }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For a beginner this code looks okay. Good job using strict equality comparisons - i.e. `===`. The indentation is mostly consistent, although the first indentation level is 4 spaces while all subsequent levels appear to be 2 spaces.

The biggest thing I would change is spacing. For the sake of readability, it helps to add spacing around operators - especially binary operators like `===`, `>`, `=`, etc. You could utilize a linter like [ESLint](https://eslint.org/), JSHint, etc. ESLint has rules like [space-infix-ops](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/space-infix-ops).

> While formatting preferences are very personal, a number of style
> guides require spaces around operators, such as:
>
> ```
> var sum = 1 + 2;
> ```
>
> The proponents of these extra spaces believe it make
> the code easier to read and can more easily highlight potential
> errors, such as:
>
> ```
> var sum = i+++2;
> ```
>
> While this is valid JavaScript syntax, it is hard to
> determine what the author intended.

<sup>[1](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/space-infix-ops)</sup>

I tried passing `0` to the function and it returned `[0, 1]`, which is the same output if I pass `2`. Theoretically it should return an empty array when `0` is passed.

The first and second else cases could be simplified to just an `else`, since the loop won't run unless `i` is less than `n` and for the case of 2 it would never be the case that 3 is less than 2. So it can be simplified like this:

```
function fibonacciGenerator (n) {
    var output = [];
    if (n === 1) {
      output = [0];
    } else {
      output = [0, 1];
      for (var i=3; i <= n; i++) {
        output.push(output[i-3] + output[i-2]);
      }
    }
    return output;
}
```

In more advanced JavaScript the [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) keyword could be used to declare `output` so it can't be over-written, which would require exclusively using the `.push()` method to add elements to the output array. Using `const` when re-assignment isn't needed is a good habit because it can help avoid [accidental re-assignment and other bugs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/278653/244085).

Alternatively, the function could return early in the base cases - e.g. when `n` is `1`.

Comment: Awesome, I appreciate this a lot. I hadn't realized that I only needed one else condition. I'll have to revisit this once I get to learning about const, too!